# How should you specify Pandas Series datatype and index datatype?

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.8

There seems to be very little documentation out there on the internet about using Python type hints with Pandas objects.

I would like to specify the types of a Series's data and index.

By some reverse-engineering, I've managed to find a specification which Pyright is happy with, but it's not clear to me what some of the type arguments are meant to represent.

My naive approach would be something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

s: pd.Series[int, str] = pd.Series(
    [1, 2], index=["a", "b"]
)
```

But Pyright says it's expecting *six* arguments:

```
Too few type arguments provided for class "Series"; expected 6 but received 2
```

By trial-and-error I've discovered that the six elements are:

1. The data type, expressed as `list[int]`
2. The index type, expressed as `list[str]`
3. Can seemingly be anything. Nothing I put in this field makes Pyright complain.
4. Same as previous argument.
5. Something called `__type_of_copy@Series`. I can't find any information on what this means.
6. Something called `__type_of_fastpath@Series`. I also can't find anything about this.

For `__type_of_copy` and `__type_of_fastpath` it seems to want `bool` types, so I can finally express my Series type like this:

```py
s: pd.Series[list[float], list[str], None, None, bool, bool] = pd.Series(
    [1, 2], index=["a", "b"]
)
```

But this seems pretty crazy to me. My questions are:

- Why is this seemingly so undocumented?
- What are `__type_of_copy` and `__type_of_fastpath`?
- Is this an accepted way of doing type hints for Pandas Series?